# Using Maven, how to add an artifact to the target artifact but not to the build

Tags: maven

I want to add a .dylib file to a CentOS-build jar.   I'm compiling on

- CentOS 7.6,
- mvn 3.5.2,
- Java 1.8.0

How can I make the .dylb a dependency of the package, but not the build when I type "mvn clean package".

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.jfs.os.native</groupId>
          <artifactId>jfs-mac-x86_64</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0-mfs</version>
          <type>dylib</type>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: If it a resource, it should go to `src/main/resources`.

Comment: It's an artifact downloaded from a maven repo.

Comment: What problem do you experience if it is part of the build?

Comment: Part of the generated error is "Failed to create assembly: Error adding file-set for 'jfs.os.native:jfs.os.native:dylib,3.1.0-mfs' to archive: Error adding file-set."  And lastly, "No such archiver: 'dylib'. -> [Help 1]"